# Count Distinct with Multiple Conditions

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to do a `DISTINCTCOUNT` of customer IDs after the following filters are applied:

```
1) [type_] = "Subscription" 

2) [state_] = "Active" 

3) [archivedAt] = Blank())
```

How can I change the below to not use "Filter" because it says I'm using it too many times.

> Too many arguments were passed to the FILTER function. The maximum
>   argument count for the function is 2.

Thanks!

Comment: You should had the formula you tried here, a sample of the model, schema/sample data and desired output.
Looks to me that you are trying to pass multiple arguments instead of using boolean conditions "&&"

Comment: It doesn't say you're "using it too many times", it says you're passing too many arguments to the filter. If you want to filter for multiple conditions, you can separate them with `&&` or `||` depending on whether you want 'AND' or 'OR' logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `CALCULATE` instead of using `FILTER`. Calculate can handle multiple filters in it.

```
 YourMeasure =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Table[Customer ID] ),
    [type_] = "Subscription",
    [state_] = "Active",
    [archivedAt] = BLANK ()
)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax